# Name and official (?) rules for this cards game I half remembered

Tags: identify-this-game

There is this card game I like to play whenever I have 5+ people around and the group includes some 'not so serious' gamers.  The problem is I have sort of forgotten the real rules over the years and I feel like I forget a few every time I teach new people to play.  Here is the basic idea:

- Deal our all the deck.
- Whoever goes first plays either a single card, a pair, triple, or 4 of a kind.
- The player to their left then must play the same thing but with a higher number (if a pair of 4s was played the next person has to play a pair of 5's or higher).
- 2s are considered the highest card, playing one two at any time will 'win' the trick and let you lead a new card.
- The first person out is the... president? Some title. At the start of the next round the last person out must give the president their 2 best cards, and the president then returns 2 cards of his choice.

Soooo what game am I playing?  Are there real rules for it I can brush up on?

Comment: I've played this game before and it was called 2s (but I'm not convinced that's the proper title).  The game didn't seem to present the player with much in the way of choices, and so I got fed up with it!

Comment: I have played this game under the name 'scum'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [Daifugō](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daifugo)

Your playing with the "Deuce Means Clear" optional rule.

Answer (score 8):

You are playing asshole, a classic drinking game. Rules vary, but here's a pretty standard set: http://www.webtender.com/handbook/games/asshole.game

Answer (score 5):

There's a few names for this game: Asshole is the one I've heard most often. President or Janitor are other names I've heard when Authority Figures are around.

Wizards of the Coast releases a version of this game under two names - the old one is The Great Dalmuti, and the new one is Dilbert-themed and called Corporate Shuffle. (I've never played Great Dalmuti). These ones vary in two respects - first, you play down rather than up (so you need to play 4s to beat 5s), and the number of copies in the deck is equal to the card value. (Only one 1, two 2, down to 10 tens). This adds a touch of balance, since you can overwhelm the better cards through sheer numbers.

Answer (score 4):

## [Big Two](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Two)

It sounds like Big Two, to me. Then again, Daifugo and Big 2 are close relatives...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to upgrade this card game to something slightly more "shiny"... I can recommend [Frank's Zoo](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/340/franks-zoo) which uses these basic rules but has cute animals and some interesting (and varyingly optional) rules twists.  At heart it's still Asshole :)